# Is there general algorithm for sorting with constraints?

Tags: sorting

Say I have list of URLs and it already have some sorting; now let's add some constraint - say having more than two links with a same domain in a row is bad.

Actually I could have few constraints - two, three, five, unlikely more.

And now I want to resort my original list while maintaining some balance between initial sorting and my constraints. And this equilibrium line should be configurable in some way.

Right now all I have in mind is very straighforward (and I believe error-prone) bruteforce approach - just iterate over the list, count every statistic I care about, decide to move links up or down by some heuristic, recalculate statistics and move further...

Comment: BTW list size is about 30-50 elements. Algorithm I search for might not be most efficient one, rather relative simplicity is very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I delayed solving this problem; but I came up with one possible solution and I'll try to describe it.

It works for a problem "no more than N of elements with same property in a row" - links with same domain in my original case.

So:

1. Identify "bad" places in your list - and remember them as intervals of indices.
2. For each interval:

   - extend that interval in both sides - take care to not exceed bounds of array (and probably bounds of another intervals)
   - extension size should depend on interval size
   - shuffle that interval unless it looks ok relative to our condition

In this way we perturb sorting only in limited intervals, and general sorting shouldn't change much.

Probably we should have special case when more than half of our list is single "bad" interval - just distribute it uniformly for example.

Answer (score 0):

there is an IEEE paper about a general algorithm for sorting with constraints....

if yu wud like to read it, then here is the link:
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp;jsessionid=nBBXQnGZGd9bRJhQfjzWQGhLm97BQ7xLG9LChppLPBvfJ0Sb2hRh!1364212599?arnumber=5358031&contentType=Conference+Publications

Comment: Too bad it isn't in free access. Moreover I afraid that this exact paper is a bit offtopic, but reading references gave me a thought - I should have penalty function and now it's an optimization problem.